# Reading from a File and print to another File

Tags: c, arrays, function

I have a file test.txt which looks like this:

```
5 6
sugli*
odiati
tiri*n
tri*cd
oe*poi
```

The first two numbers are the array dimension in which all these words have to be put.

The code for the following task is (*fileIn* is the *test.txt* file):

```
int row, col;
fscanf(fileIn, "%d %d%*c", &row, &col);
int cruciverba[row][col];

for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
        cruciverba[i][j] = fgetc(fileIn);
    }
    char space = fgetc(fileIn);
}
```

The array is now created. Now I should write a function (or more) that writes string to another file, but not every string in the array, just the ones that have length >= 2 horizontally and vertically. Note that the `'*'` is the string separator.
The goal is to have a output.txt file that contains these strings:

```
sugli
odiati
tiri
tri
cd
oe
poi

sotto
udire
giri
lai
it
co
indi
```

I know how to output the strings but I don't have any idea how to approach the issue. Any suggestion?

Comment: You do NOT have strings. You have not left space for the *nul-terminating* character at the end of each row of characters (e.g. `col + 1`). You have *character arrays*. You can write them out using `fputc`.

Comment: I have to check their length before putting them out. That's the problem I don't know how to solve

Comment: This is where you have to be a little smart about it. I would suggest making them strings by leaving room for the *nul-terminating* character and writing the *nul-terminating* character (`0`) after you read each word. Otherwise, you will need to store the length of each word. (you generally store this as the `1st` char in each row -- meaning read each char in the word and start your save loop at `j` at `1`, then when you read the last char, you set `cruciverba[i][0] = j`) When you write them out with `fputc` you use `for (j = 1; j < cruciverba[i][0]; j++)`. (more work than strings)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is designed to torment you on a number of levels. From *character oriented* input, character array verses string understanding, array indexing, text file format, and a host of additional subtle issues, this is designed to force you to focus on a character-by-character level.

To begin with you have your data file that contains your array bounds followed by `5-rows` of `7-characters` each (you must account for the `'\n'` char terminating each line). Your array storage is `5-row` by `6-col`. Which means from a *character oriented* input standpoint, you must account for the read of the `'\n'` while ignoring it from a data/index standpoint.

(**note:** while the intent of the problem seems to have you read into a 2D-array, you could read `row*col` of chars into a 1D array as well -- that approach is not without its challenges either)

After navigating the read into your array, you are faced with output the array, while considering only `[A-Za-z]` (`alpha`) characters as part of each line, the `'*'` characters as a `'\n'` and the end of each row as a `'\n'` as well.

There is no easy, or one right, way to approach this. Regardless how you do, this is where you are going to have to really focus on indexing gymnastics to arrive at a routine that provides the proper output. The approach below uses a `7-char` buffer and a buffer-index to buffer each wanted char and to write the buffer to `stdout` when all conditions are met (e.g. a `'*'` or end-of-row is reached). Below is a commented example of one way to approach the problem. I have left the second part of manipulating the to you, but with the examples provided here and by BLUEPIXY, you have a couple of examples that show you have to approach handling the indexing. Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int row, col, i, idx, j, c;
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }
    row = col = i = idx = j = c = 0;  /* initialize all values */

    /* validate row and col data read */
    if (fscanf (fp, "%d %d%*c", &row, &col) != 2) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid read of row/col.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char cruciverbal[row][col]; /* variable length array to data */
    char buf[col+1];            /* buffer to assist in printing  */

    for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {         /* for each row in array */
        for (j = 0; j < col; j++) {     /* for each char in row  */
            if ((c = fgetc (fp)) == EOF)    /* jump if EOF */
                goto readdone;
            else {
                cruciverbal[i][j] = c;  /* store char in array   */
            }
        }
        fgetc (fp);  /* discard newline in file */
    }
readdone:

    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);   /* close file if not stdin   */

    /* print characters to stdout */
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            if (isalpha (cruciverbal[i][j]))    /* if [A-Za-Z]  */
                buf[idx++] = cruciverbal[i][j]; /* buffer char  */
            else {
                if (idx > 1) {          /* check if buffer > 1  */
                    buf[idx] = 0;       /* nul-terminate buffer */
                    printf ("%s\n", buf);
                    idx = 0;            /* reset buffer index   */
                }
                else {                  /* if buf < 2, print \n */
                    fputc ('\n', stdout);
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }   /* if last char in row is [A-Za-z] */
        if (isalpha (cruciverbal[i][j-1])) {
            if (idx > 1) {
                buf[idx] = 0;           /* nul-terminate buffer */
                printf ("%s\n", buf);
            }
            else if (idx == 0)          /* if buffer empty */
                fputc ('\n', stdout);   /* output newline  */
        }
        idx = 0;                        /* reset buf index */
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/cruciverbal <../dat/56array.txt
sugli
odiati
tiri
tri
cd
oe
poi
```

Look over both answers and let us know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define TRIGGER '*'

void out(FILE *fileOut, char *buff, int value){
//this function is output buffer
    static int pos = 0;
    if(value == TRIGGER){
        buff[pos] = '\0';
        if(pos >= 2)
            fprintf(fileOut, "%s\n", buff);
        pos = 0;
    } else {
        buff[pos++] = value;
    }
}
```

...

//at main

```
FILE *fileOut = fopen("out.txt", "w");
int side[2] = {row, col};
for(int s = 0; s < 2; ++s){
    char buff[side[s]+1];
    *buff = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < side[s]; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < side[1-s]; j++) {
            out(fileOut, buff, s ? cruciverba[j][i] : cruciverba[i][j]);
        }
        out(fileOut, buff, TRIGGER);
    }
    fprintf(fileOut, "\n");
}
fclose(fileOut);
```